# How to figure out if a Metastore object is a view or a table?

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to find if a metastore object is a Table or a View.

For example, we can use this SQL query:

```
 Describe detail mydb.mytable
```

that returns metadata about the table:

[image]

The `format` column here tells us that this object is a table - "**delta**" (table).

Is there an equivalent query that I can use to check if an object is a View?

Note: there seems to be no equivalent for the above `Describe detail` query for a view. I tried bellow:

```
Describe detail mydb.myview
```

But I am getting this error:

```
com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: information_schema.tables; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [information_schema, tables], [], false

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$2(CheckAnalysis.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis$2$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:357)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
...
```

Comment: Just curious - if the database name is known - why not try `SHOW TABLE in <DB_NAME>` and filter the resulting dataframe based on the isTemporary column. Would that work ? Views would show up as true.

Comment: Thank you @rainingdistros. However that query `SHOW TABLES in <DB_NAME>`  shows the `isTemporary` column as `false` for both views and tables.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - I tried writing a dataframe to a table and view using below code `df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("sample_table")
df.createTempView("sample_view")` Then tried looking for it using `show tables` Output is as follows `database tableName isTemporary
default sample_table false
 sample_view true` The formatting is all wierd, but sample_view shows up as true for isTemporary...

Answer (score 1):

There is no column/attribute to differentiate between tables and views in a schema in Databricks deltalake.
`SHOW TABLES` will get everything; tables and views. However, `SHOW VIEWS` will get only the views.

So you can get only the delta tables list by

```
tables_list = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES FROM schema_name")\
                   .select("tableName")\
                   .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)\
                   .collect()
views_list = spark.sql("SHOW VIEWS FROM schema_name")\
                  .select("viewName")\
                  .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)\
                  .collect()
tables_only_list = [x for x in tables_list if x not in views_list]
```

`isTemporary` has nothing to do with the differentiation between tables and views. It only tells if the object was created with TEMP keyword. For example

```
CREATE VIEW test_view AS ...
CREATE TEMP VIEW test_temp_view AS ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unity Catalog you can query `information_schema.tables` which contains column `table_type`. According to documentation this column can have values `base table` or `view`.